# How to get value from list of tuple?

Tags: python

I have a list below:

ma_list:

```
{'Short_windows': 1, 'Long_windows': 2, 'Cover_windows': 2}
```

But I can't use `ma_list[0]` to get `Short_windows's` value 1.

How to get `Short_windows`, `Long_windows`, `Cover_windows's` value?

If I try to print `ma_list['Short_windows']`

It will show errors below:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: ma_list["Short_windows"]?

Comment: It's a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), not a list.

Comment: Just because you write it in an order, it doesn't mean it is stored in that order. Also, your title doesn't match your question at all.

Comment: What do you pass in as `ma_list`? Obviously it’s not a dictionary but a list. Does `print(ma_list[0])` not work?

Comment: @easyway If your question was resolved, don't forget to [accept (and upvote :P) an answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ma_list` is a [dict](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm), not [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

Since this being a dictionary, you can get value via keys :

```
ma_dict = {'Short_windows': 1, 'Long_windows': 2, 'Cover_windows': 2}
ma_dict['Short_windows'] = 1
```

Dictionaries are unordered in Python. If you do not care about the order of the entries and want to access the keys or values by index anyway, you can use `ma_dict.keys()[0]` and `ma_dict.values()[0]` or `ma_dict.items()[0]`.

If you do care about the order of the entries, starting with Python 2.7 you can use [collections.orderdDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) OR [odict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odict/1.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

That's not a `list`, its a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), and you need to access the values using the keys:

```
>>> d = {'Short_windows': 1, 'Long_windows': 2, 'Cover_windows': 2}
>>> d['Short_windows']
1
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...     print key, value
... 
Short_windows 1
Long_windows 2
Cover_windows 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dic.get('key')` to get a certain value. 
But since dictionaries are **not ordered** there is no `get.(index)` method. 
You can use an `OrderedDic` to keep the order of your elements.

The documentation for `OrderedDic` is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict